# subframes using tkinter in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to divide my frames into more subframes and call a button for one subframe, but my in my code below, my suframes appears to away from my frame. I would be grateful if someone could help me.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tkenter 

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.OUT) #Luminária A
GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.OUT) #Luminária B
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.IN) #Luz ambiente no setor
GPIO.setup(19, GPIO.IN) #Pessoas no setor

GPIO.output(5, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(6, GPIO.LOW)

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)


def leD():

    if ((GPIO.input(5)) and (GPIO.input(6))):
        GPIO.output(5, GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(6, GPIO.LOW)
        app.frames[Acionamento].vendasFrame.vendasAcionamento["text"]="Lights on"

    else:
        GPIO.output(5, GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(6, GPIO.HIGH)
        app.frames[Acionamento].vendasFrame.vendasAcionamento["text"]="Lights off"

def sairr():
    GPIO.cleanup()
    exit()


class showAcionam(tk.Tk):


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        frame = Acionamento(container, self)

        self.frames[Acionamento] = frame

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(Acionamento)


    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class Acionamento(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Acionamento", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(padx=5,padx=5)

        #Subframe 1
        vendasFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        vendasFrame.pack(side=left, anchor="center")
        vendasAcionamento = tk.Button(vendasFrame, text="Luminárias desligadas", command = leD)
        vendasAcionamento.pack(side="top")
        self.vendasAcionamento = vendasAcionamento


        #Subframe 2
        engenhariaFrame = tk,Frame(self)
        engenhariaFrame.pack(side="left", anchor="center")


app = showAcionam()
app.mainloop()
```

Error:

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/home/pi/TCC.py", line 65, in leD
         app.frames[Acionamento].vendasFrame.vendasAcionamento["text"] = "100% de iluminação"
    AttributeError: 'Acionamento' object has no atribute 'vendasFrame'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the same problem as in previous question.

You have to use `self.`

```
self.vendasFrame = tk.Frame(self)
```

`vendasFrame` is local variable and exists only inside method `__ini__`. `self.vendasFrame` is object variable and you have access to this variable outside this method.

Comment: Ok, I got it and solved it! What would you recommend to divide a frame into subframes? I am trying to do that with pack but the main frame title is too far away from subframes. Could you give me some example?

Comment: you use `padx` so you create margin between title and frames. As I remember you can use tuple to set only left margin `padx=(5, 0)`. BTW. if you keep only one widget (Button) in subframe then there is no sense to create subframe.

Comment: BTW. you can `align` text in `Label`. see images: https://github.com/furas/my-python-codes/tree/master/tkinter/grid-pack-align